How to search across multiple cells for text then copy that cell to a different cell
I am trying to search multiple cells for a single line of text.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("name*",V2)),V2,"")  

works perfectly, but the text is in different cells.
When I try  I get #SPILL!
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("name*",P2:ED2)),P2:ED2,"") 

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance..

I don't know what result you expect. If a single value, then maybe like this:
=IFERROR(INDEX(P2:ED2,MATCH("name*",P2:ED2,0)),"")


If you are getting a #SPILL! that means it is returning multiple records, then you could have tried using the following to get a single record:


• Formula used in cell P5
=@FILTER(P2:ED2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("name",P2:ED2)))


Or, To retain multiple records use with out @ <-- Implicit Intersection Operator.
=FILTER(P2:ED2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("name",P2:ED2)))



=IFERROR(INDEX(P2:ED2,MATCH("name*",P2:ED2,0)),"")  worked.  Thank you for your response.

@mextor what I have posted it also works. Not sure what is your Excel Version!
